# Get id of recipient of each conversation

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table like this.

```
| id-AI | from    | to    | text         |created_date
+----+---------+-------+-------------+-------------
| 1  | 7       | 1     | from 7 to 1  |2015-11-06 04:59:14 
| 2  | 1       | 2     | from 1 to 2  |2015-11-06 04:57:06
| 3  | 7       | 1     | from 7 to 1  |2015-11-06 04:25:45
| 4  | 1       | 6     | from 1 to 6  |2015-11-06 04:25:32 
| 5  | 1       | 5     | from 1 to 5  |2015-11-06 04:25:16
```

I want a list like this.A list of users who knocked me or I knock him/her or we had a long conversation. the list I want should be in latest order just like facebook messaging.

```
| users |
+-------+
| 7    
| 2     
| 6
| 5
```

1 is main user_id. get list where 1 is involved(either in to or in from) then this is called conversation.

Comment: What's the problem? Write a query that finds him in the `from`, another query that finds him in `to`, and combine them with `UNION`.

Comment: will it be in latest order by date?

Comment: It will be if you use `ORDER BY created_date DESC`.

Comment: Could you please give the sql query. I tried with UNION and ORDER BY but my result is not what I want.thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following query:

```
SELECT IF (`from` = 1, `to`, `from`)
FROM mytable
WHERE 1 IN (`from`, `to`)
ORDER BY created_date DESC
```

This will return either the creator or the recipient of *each* conversation in which `user_id = 1` is involved.

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/bb5d0/1)

The get an *ordered* set of *distinct* `user_id` values use this query:

```
SELECT IF (`from` = 1, `to`, `from`)
FROM mytable
WHERE 1 IN (`from`, `to`)
GROUP BY IF (`from` = 1, `to`, `from`)
ORDER BY MAX(created_date) DESC
```

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/bb5d0/8)

Comment: It is returning multiple values. I want a distinct list of users. obviously there are several entry of one user id in either to or in from field as it is conversation.

Comment: @RajibHossen Have a look at the edit I made.

Answer (score 0):

Using UNION:

```
SELECT user
FROM (SELECT to AS user, created_date
      FROM mytable
      WHERE from = 1)
      UNION
      SELECT from AS user, created_date
      FROM mytable
      WHERE to = 1) x
GROUP BY user
ORDER BY MAX(created_date) DESC
```